# CdkStepper usage throwing NullR3InjectorError

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm trying to import `CdkStepperModule` to properly use `cdk-steps` and `cdk-stepper` to build a stepper. The app build is successful, but in console, this error occurs on trying to use the component.

```
ng-admin.min.js:54419 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[CdkStepper -> CdkStepper]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for CdkStepper!
```

I have tried the following:

- Importing `CdkStepperModule` in the module where `cdk-steps` is being used
- Adding `CdkStepperModule` in app module `@NgModule` imports

Both of these did not work.

Comment: I can see in the code here that this is properly exported: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/stepper/stepper-module.ts

Comment: see that you need use as provider `providers: [{ provide: CdkStep, useExisting: TheClassOfYourComponent }],`. It's a bit more complex, but in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7svf9j?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/&file=src%2Fmain.ts) you have a custom stepper with icons, and you can see an example in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/examples)